# Feature Request : Tracking all the game development competition

Tags: feature-request

What about having a new feature here in GameDevelopment that track all the upcoming and to-be-announced game developers event/jam/competitions.

A interactive horizontal bar at the bottom of the page or a different page dedicated for tracking all these events.

Mockup :
[image]

This will show all the important dates and milestones for up-coming or running competitions. In this mock up I am showing two deadlines. But this bar could include many more.

Why : Because most here are students or working on a full time job somewhere. Its not possible for everyone to track all these competitions. And there is no place where all these are listed and always up to date(correct me if I am wrong). So, why no do something here?

I think this will be a great addition to this community.

**Update:**

> who would be gathering and maintaining the data

The [CHAOS team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character)?

> stackexchange is really focusing down pretty exclusively on generating answers which will be valid for years/decades

Wholeheartedly agree. I thought that it would be nice to have a nice feature for only this SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **[HERE](http://compohub.net/) IT IS!**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you might like to propose a [community ad](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/675/community-promotion-ads-2012) for this site. (It would be neat if the ad was itself a chart like you originally proposed, but I see ads are required to be static images.)

Comment: Yeh, too bad that Community Ad only supports static images.

Comment: @iamcreasy: The static image is just to take you to the actual site, which would be dynamic. Also "CompoHub" is a terrible name. If I were looking for a site about game development events, that's not what I would be searching for.

Comment: @nicol-bolas I didn't find either, hence started this question. Anyway, [added](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/675/community-promotion-ads-2012) to the community ad question. But, the banner isn't sharp enough to be descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

I think this would definitely be a useful bit of data to be able to access.

But I'm not certain that it's really appropriate for the stackexchange network, particularly since it's not clear who would be gathering and maintaining the data, and how that data would be managed;  it's very different from the Q&A things that we're doing here now.

I could easily see a bit of data like this being presented at (for example) gamedev.net, or perhaps tigsource.com.  But stackexchange is really focusing down pretty exclusively on generating answers which will be valid for years/decades, not on the continuous production of infographics which become outdated in only a few days time.

Comment: The other tricky one is triage - how do we decide on what to include?

Comment: I updated my question on your answer. @trevor-powell I regularly go through gamedev.net(dont know about tigsource) but didn't really see any regular updated news on these events? Its more like you-will-find-it-only-if-you-are-looking-for-it. That's why I am a bit frustrated about this data. And the data wont be static it they get updated if this widget changes itself with the event. Yes, I know its messy, but isn't thats why the accumulated information will be valuable.

Comment: @jonathan-dickinson I was thinking it more like a notification for two things. One, shows us the event and two, gives us a time range to submit the game. i.e. IndieCade is accepting game throughout Jan,1 to May,1. More like a Gantt chart.

Comment: @iamcreasy I really like the idea, I did upvote - I have the same concerns as Trevor though; and additionally how we decide which competitions are important enough to feature on the timeline (triage) - possibly only ones with monetary prizes? I am not sure. Maybe I should answer instead of spamming this answer with comments.

Comment: @jonathan-dickinson If you ask me i would be able to tell 10-12 worth mentioning competition. But I am sure there are more then 50(wild guess). So, maybe why not jam *all* that we know of? Is it gonna be way too difficult to maintain when you have a pre-made list? Firstly, we can remove the regional competitions. That would shorten the list a great deal.